# CouchDB Simple SELECT the right way?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, couchdb-futon

I am building a very simple users system on Apache CouchDB. I have build a simple view to search users by email:

```
by_email
map
function(doc) {
 if (doc.kind == "user" && doc.email) emit(doc.email, doc.name);
 }
```

this returns

```
 {"id"=>"00006a80-723b-012f-6b38-1040f398478e", "key"=>"spiderman@spiderman.ai", "value"=>"Spiderman"}
```

Now I might be missing something very stupid (if this is the case I do I apologize) but why you can only retrieve 2 fields (3 if we count the ID) from this view ?

Like in a normal situation you might want to search your users database starting from the email or user ID and retrieve the full document.

Now I did read the example at http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html (look up by key) 
and, unless I am missing something very trivial, the result there is incomplete too as it will return only the name of users with a certain age and nothing more.

I fail to understand how this would make of a proper use: if you query your db of clients, suppliers, whatever you will want the full document back and not just 1 of the values or 2.

So my solution was another view:

```
mailplus
map
function(doc) { if (doc.kind == "user" && doc.email)  emit(doc.email,doc) }
```

so to return me the email but also the full document as value. This works but as you can imagine it is considerably slower in a bigger database.

So the question is: is there any better way to do a simple query to retrieve full details about a user searching by email for example using CouchDB - NoSQL ?

I know that the temptation to answer "this is wrong as you can't think SQL in NoSQL" but wait: in a real world application, thinking as NoSQL in terms of Documents and not tables/rows etc, you might want the full document for a user. Imagine you have a simple system to retrieve client details. You need the full document. You do not need to know the id and key  only when you are supplying the key, email, in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Been a while since I've used couchdb but i believe this is still accurate.

You can only retrieve those 2 fields because that's all you put into the view. Internally couchdb tracks the id of the document that corresponds to each emitted key/value. You can then use the `include_docs` option when querying that view to have couchdb lookup the documents by id ( see the [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Access.2BAC8-Query))

The other choice as you outlined is to have the full document in view, which will make the index much bigger

Comment: so a possible solution is to use e.g. the email as the id (or the username)? This would enforce unique users (despite the limitation in replication) which is another issue. Honestly I think I am missing something: isn't validating a record (validates_uniqueness_of :email, :username) something fairly basic and expected in web development? As it is fetching a full profile for a user e.g. when the user wants to modify his details etc.

Comment: for such uniqueness validation you can emit twice for each doc, first with email as the key and second with name, after that juch check resulting view for exising of two keys (see couchdb wiki). but it won't solve the issue because someone could insert the record after your check, moreover in case of replication it is possible to insert conflicting key on different servers, how do you resolve the conflict? the proper soluction should use database constraints like mysql, afair rails doesn't use them in their activerecord. couchdb has serverside validators but you cannot make subquery

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to emit the doc. Simply add `include_docs=true` to your query parameters. Full docs is on the wiki[1](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can emit part of the document with emit(doc.email, {name: doc.name, age: doc.age})